# How did Gus fulfil his promise that Hector et al wouldn't return?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

I already forgot this particular storyline. In Better Call Saul S03E04, Gus assures [Lyle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118611/what-happened-to-lyle-in-bcs-bb) and the other Los Pollos Hermanos employees that Hector Salamanca, Ignacio Varga, et al [wouldn't return](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pixVVVlm4tM):

> "This is America. Here, the righteous have no reason to fear. Here, those men have no power." And when they saw that I had no fear of them, they ran like the cowards they are. Back across the border. They will not return. We will move on from this. My friends, I promise you... that together, we will prosper.

Gus of course had made up a fake story about how Hector was bullying Gus for money.

But how did Gus actually make sure that Hector et al didn't return? Like, what, Gus complained to Bolsa or Eladio who then forbade Hector from ever setting foot in an LPH branch?

I checked out the episode again, and it seems there's no resolution in this episode.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How Gus fulfilled the promise? Or why Gus promised something he couldn't guarantee?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite how was gus able to make hector not come back to LPH?

Comment: He also claimed that the Salamancas were merely carrying out a shakedown. His speech to his employees was more of a motivational pep talk and attempt to sweep the events under the carpet (coupled with financial reward - the overtime he promised - and offer of counselling) than an actual truthful explanation and promise that it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He kind of doesn't. In episode 6 of season 3 of *Breaking Bad*, 'Sunset', Marco and Leonel Salamanca [turn up at Pollos and just kind of sit there](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Sunset#Act_I). While they weren't present during Hector's visit, and their actions aren't quite the same, it's a somewhat-similar instance of chicken-restaurant-based cartel intimidation — Cynthia at least seems to recognise that something's not right. Presumably Hector himself might have tried something similar if he wasn't confined to a wheelchair by that point.

You know, I'm starting to think that this Gustavo Fring chap doesn't tell the truth 100% of the time.

Comment: I've also heard he is an ABSOLUTE stickler on deep-fryer cleanliness...

Comment: riiiiight thanks Paul D. Waite. do you agree with this 'His speech to his employees was more of a motivational pep talk and attempt to sweep the events under the carpet (coupled with financial reward - the overtime he promised - and offer of counselling) than an actual truthful explanation and promise that it wouldn't happen again.' ?

Comment: @BCLC: does it seem like I don't? Does the literal meaning of Gus's words make it difficult for you to interpret their context? Have I not answered the actual question you said you had, i.e. "how was gus able to make hector not come back to LPH"?

Comment: @CGCampbell This comment is... acceptable